# Getting the value of the selected Radio button in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have three radiobuttons like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="IsPerCentOrDollar" value="1" data-bind="checked: IsPerCentOrDollar" />
<span>Percentage Amount</span>

<input type="radio" name="IsPerCentOrDollar" value="2" data-bind="checked: IsPerCentOrDollar" />
<span>Dollar Amount</span>
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DiscountValue, new { @class = "form-control", @data_bind = "value: DiscountValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', disable: IsPerCentOrDollar() == '3'", @maxlength = "50" })
<input type="radio" value="3" class="freeShipping" name="free" data-bind="checked: IsPerCentOrDollar" />
<label>Free Shipping</label>
```

IsPerCentOrDollar is used to disable the text box when Free Shipping is selected.

```
self.IsPerCentOrDollar = ko.observable();
```

The viewmodel:

```
function CouponViewModel(data) {
        selfCoupon = this;
        self.IsPerCentOrDollar = ko.observable();

        selfCoupon.discountType = ko.observable();
        selfCoupon.Code = ko.observable(data.Code);
        selfCoupon.DiscountValue = ko.observable(data.DiscountValue);
        selfCoupon.DiscountLevel = ko.observable("1");
    };
```

I have set the default value of DiscountLevel to 1.
This remains no matter which radio button is clicked.

So what I want is to have the value of the radiobutton clicked to come in DiscountLevel.

Any clues, suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I think it could looks like:

```
function CouponViewModel(data) {
    selfCoupon = this;
    self.IsPerCentOrDollar = ko.observable("1");

    selfCoupon.discountType = ko.observable();
    selfCoupon.Code = ko.observable(data.Code);
    selfCoupon.DiscountValue = ko.observable(data.DiscountValue);
    selfCoupon.DiscountLevel = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.IsPerCentOrDollar();
    });
};
```

if you also want to check first radio button at the beggining (quite logic for me) or just:

```
    self.IsPerCentOrDollar.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        selfCoupon.DiscountLevel(newValue);
    });
```

if you don't want to do that.

This will set DiscountLevel for value of IsPerCentOrDollar, each time when IsPerCentOrDollar change.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
self.IsPerCentOrDollar.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    selfCoupon.DiscountLevel(newValue);
});
```

**Edit**

```
function CouponViewModel(data) {
    selfCoupon = this;
    selfCoupon.IsPerCentOrDollar = ko.observable();        

    selfCoupon.discountType = ko.observable();
    selfCoupon.Code = ko.observable(data.Code);
    selfCoupon.DiscountValue = ko.observable(data.DiscountValue);
    selfCoupon.DiscountLevel = ko.observable("1");

    selfCoupon.IsPerCentOrDollar.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        selfCoupon.DiscountLevel(newValue);
    });
};
```

Comment: gives this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: ho this is maybe not self.IsPerCentOrDollar but selfCoupon.IsPerCentOrDollar

Comment: where is declared self ?cause a i see self.IsPerCentOrDollar = ko.observable();

Comment: Don't think self needs to be declared.No?